# Controller return value displays the error[Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' ] in view

Tags: php, laravel

The controller perfectly executes the query and return the results. But in the view file I got the error **undefined variable**, the Controller code is :

```
public function edit($id)
{
$pid=$id;
$pedit = DB::table('users')->where('id', $pid)->first();
return view('sample', compact('$pedit'));
}
```

View code is :

```
{!! Form::Id('Id', $value = {{$pedit}}, ['class' => 'form-control1', 
   'placeholder' => 'Id']) !!}
```

What is the mistake in my view code

Comment: `$value = {{$pedit}}` does not make sense when inside `{!! !!}`

Comment: What Undefined variable....?Paste error here.

Comment: '$pedit'  is varibale does not seems declare. please verify the code

Comment: you need `compact('pedit')`

Comment: I've updated my error  [(2/2) ErrorException
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\movecab\resources\views\sample.blade.php)]

Comment: @apokryfos Then how 'ld I change my code

Comment: @madalinivascu No it's not working

Comment: @apokryfos yes u r correct but when remove the {!! !!} the code get printed

Comment: How about if you replace the `$value = {{ $pedit }}` with just `$pedit` ? You can greatly benefit from a tutorial. These questions are to fundamental and indicate that you haven't gone through the trouble of **properly** learning about the language and framework you're trying to use.

Comment: Yeah,I'm new to laravel

Comment: remove dollar sign in the string. if that doesnt work again try sending with `with` method.

Comment: If you are using the `laravelcollective/html` package, I don't think there is an `id()` function and if there was you should call it with lowercase `Form::id()`. And you can't set a variable value inside a function call like that. Just pass the `$pedit` variable as the second argument `Form::id('Id', $pedit)` (without the curly brackets). Also like some users already mentioned, replace `compact('$pedit')` with `compact('pedit')` (without the `$` sign).